# Verify signature of server certificate using public key of certificate in bundle in iOS

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, nsurlconnection

I have to verify the signature of the certificate received from the server using the public key in the certificate stored in the bundle of my application.

I think the problem is with the way I am using the signature from the certificate. I have extracted the signature from the certificate using a browser and I am using it as a string. I am not sure in which format is this string.(Could be normal utf-8 or SHA-1 but I am not sure and neither I am sure how to extract the Signature from the server certificate.)

I am using the following code but it returns an error code of -9809.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    id <NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender> sender = challenge.sender;
    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace;

    SecTrustRef trust = [protectionSpace serverTrust];
    SecCertificateRef certificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0);
    NSData* serverCertificateData = (__bridge NSData*)SecCertificateCopyData(certificate);

    const unsigned char *certificateDataBytes = (const unsigned char *)[serverCertificateData bytes];
    X509 *certificateX509 = d2i_X509(NULL, &certificateDataBytes, [serverCertificateData length]);
    NSString *issuerCN = CertificateGetIssuerCommonName(certificateX509);

    if ([self shouldTrustProtectionSpace:protectionSpace]) {

        NSString *organizationalUnit = CertificateGetOrganizationalUnit(certificateX509);



        NSString* str = @"4C 22 0D 34 9F 6F 0B 40 EE A0 56 22 70 57 75 1A B3 AC 21 A3 E3 F0 F4 D4 B9 8E CD E2 55 EE 09 7F D7 83 3C 67 68 4B 08 AB B6 00 A8 BE CD A9 73 CB 45 43 5F 67 96 15 A4 F2 4B 2D 31 0E F8 40 66 02 02 1A 39 2B A9 D7 EE AD 6A E8 FB FB AC FB 00 5F 05 5E 77 C5 9D 45 55 6F 0B 64 5F E7 93 A3 AE 52 8A 8E 7E BD BB EE E8 06 98 42 F6 F5 36 DE 9B 06 3A C9 05 6B 60 2C 4F 0A 6D C3 65 12 E8 E1 9C 36 8D F6 93 79 D7 D6 92 C0 87 EB EC 96 14 F7 FB B6 53 AC  28 A6 9B 80 0B 01 60 CA 87 10 74 EA 68 C4 34 97 AD 29 50 6B E5 29 7C 59 84 83 FD D2 4A 59 16 BB E2 6D 3C D9 D1 1E C4 AF 44 0A 85 99 B3 29 27 3D 9C 60 D9 08 77 85 FA";

        NSData* signatureData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        //Load the bundled client certificate
        NSString* certPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"root_LA" ofType:@"cer"];
        NSData* cerData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:certPath];

        CFDataRef certDataRef = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)cerData;
        SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certDataRef);

        SecPolicyRef secPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();

        SecTrustRef trust;
        SecTrustCreateWithCertificates( cert, secPolicy, &trust);
        SecTrustResultType resultType;
        SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &resultType);
        SecKeyRef publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust);

        uint8_t sha1HashDigest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
        CC_SHA1([serverCertificateData bytes], [serverCertificateData length], sha1HashDigest);

        OSStatus verficationResult = SecKeyRawVerify(publicKey,  kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA1, sha1HashDigest, CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH, [signatureData bytes], [signatureData length]);
        CFRelease(publicKey);
        CFRelease(trust);
        CFRelease(secPolicy);
        if (verficationResult == errSecSuccess) NSLog(@"Verified");
   // VerificationResult comes as -9809
    }
    else
    {
        [sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        [connection cancel];
        [self handleCertifcateVildationFailureForCN:issuerCN];
    }
}
```